# Person total correlation using R

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to calculate a person total correlation in R. It is based on this short YouTube video doing it in Excel in case this is a helpful reference for anyone: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSnq9npL4J0&feature=youtu.be

Basically I have a questionnaire with multiple items. My goal is to create a mean of each item (average of that column). Then take the average and correlate it with the individual's response. Here is an example with just one item.
I calculated the mean like this:

```
data$item1_mean <- mean(data$item1)
```

Then I tried to correlate the original response with the mean like so:

```
cor(data$item1_mean, data$item1)
```

The error I am getting is "the standard deviation is zero." This makes perfect sense because the mean column doesn't have any variability, it is just the same value all the way down the column. I am just wondering if there is still a way to calculate this correlation at all because it is possible in excel. I have also tried to just make the mean a value instead to inputting in back into the dataset and the error I get is "incompatible dimensions". This also makes sense because it is one value trying to correlate with a column. I am a little stuck on how to solve this and would appreciate any help. Thank you all!

Comment: had to fire up excel to see what the formula was doing, I think you want `set.seed(1); m <- matrix(rpois(100, 5), 10); apply(m, 1, function(x) cor(x, colMeans(m)))`

Comment: @rawr Could you break down what you wrote? I am just wondering what the numbers represent. I would appreciate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two variables used in `CORREL` from excel seem to be the means of each column of scores and the rows of scores, so for an r by c matrix, you need to use

```
for (i in 1:nrows)
  cor(r_i, colMeans(matrix))
```

example

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(
  rpois(100, 5), 10,
  dimnames = list(ID = 1:10, item = paste0('item', 1:10))
)
#     item
# ID   item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10
#   1      4     3     9     5     7     5     8     4     4      3
#   2      4     3     3     5     6     7     4     7     6      2
#   3      5     6     6     5     7     4     5     4     4      6
#   4      8     4     3     3     5     3     4     4     4      8
#   5      3     7     4     7     5     2     6     5     6      7
#   6      8     5     4     6     7     2     3     8     3      7
#   7      9     6     1     7     1     4     5     7     6      5
#   8      6    11     4     2     5     5     7     4     2      4
#   9      6     4     8     6     6     6     2     7     3      7
#   10     2     7     4     4     6     4     8     9     3      5

cm <- colMeans(m)
# item1  item2  item3  item4  item5  item6  item7  item8  item9 item10 
#   5.5    5.6    4.6    5.0    5.5    4.2    5.2    5.9    4.1    5.4 

apply(m, 1, function(x) cor(x, cm)) 
#          1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10 
# -0.2333769 -0.2257414  0.3862146  0.4491248  0.3002514  0.8108818  0.2693194  0.4351975  0.1621993  0.5799516
```

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, thank you so much! Quick question (no worries if you don't know), could you imagine why I would get some NAs even though I don't have missing data?

Comment: I answered my own question in case anyone else is figuring this out- it means the items had the same answer across all columns (no variability).